# LDAP: Difference between buildDn() and context.setAttributeValues

Tags: java, rest, ldap, spring-ldap

Being relatively new with LDAP I'm getting stuck with what exactly everything is looking for. Currently I'm trying to add a user. The common sample code usually has a create function and a buildDn function, but the code in each is usually pretty similar. Here is what I have:

```
public void create(User u) {
    Name dn = buildDn(u);
    DirContextAdapter context = new DirContextAdapter(dn);
    context.setAttributeValues("objectclass", new String[] {"top", "person"});
    context.setAttributeValue("cn", u.getName());
    context.setAttributeValue("sAMAccountName", u.getUserName());
    _ldapTemplate.bind(context);
}
```

and the buildDn function:

```
protected Name buildDn( User u ) {
    return LdapNameBuilder.newInstance()
            .add("cn", u.getName())
            .add("sAMAccountName", u.getUserName())    
            .build();
}
```

The error I'm getting when I try to add a user is a 500 error with the console saying:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.ldap.NameNotFoundException: 
[LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0310020A, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
'OU=**,OU=**,DC=**,DC=**,DC=**']; 
nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: 
[LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0310020A, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
'OU=**,OU=**,DC=**,DC=**,DC=**'];
remaining name 'sAMAccountName=**,cn=**'
```

I've replaced my user specific data with **. Since both of the functions mentioned above are add/setting attributes I'm not sure which one is going wrong and why. And maybe I'm completely missing the problem all together. TIA

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to read up on some of the basics of LDAP (tutorials are easily found if you google for it): The Distinguished Name (DN) of an entry is its unique identifier, specifying where in the LDAP tree the entry can be found. The *attributes* on an LDAP entry is the data bound to the entry.

In your example you'll need to modify your buildDn function to specify the correct position in the LDAP tree where you want to place your LDAP entry (relative to the base DN specified in your configuration). Depending on the objectClass of the LDAP entry you want to create, additional attributes may also be required (the objectClass of an entry defines which attributes are allowed and which are required)